# @react-oauth/google google login not returning access_token

Tags: reactjs, authentication, google-signin

Index.js
Here is my code for google login integration

```
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from "@react-oauth/google";
ReactDOM.render(
  <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="118420081966-s1n42272jcg4r5l4erufahti23ubp8o0.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </GoogleOAuthProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Login.js
Here i have written coomponent and capturing the resposne

```
    import { GoogleLogin } from "@react-oauth/google";

    const responseMessage = (response) => {
      console.log(response);
      setUser(response);
    };

    <GoogleLogin onSuccess={responseMessage} onError={errorMessage} />;
```

i am getting only these in response after login

```
{
  "clientId": "",
  "credential": "",
  "select_by": "";
}
```

Next while fetching user it is asking for access_token how ti get the access token.It is not returning from google

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (user) {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=${user.access_token}`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${user.access_token}`,
            Accept: "application/json",
          },
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        setProfile(res.data);
        setEmail(res.data.email);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
}, [user]);
```

Please take a look how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

use useGoogleLogin instead of GoogleLogin
here is the code

```
<button onClick={() => login()}>Sign in with Google  </button>
  const login = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: (codeResponse) => setUser(codeResponse),
    onError: (error) => console.log("Login Failed:", error),
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem. Once you receive the response, you have to decode the "credential" parameter using, for example, the jwt-decode library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode.

import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

var token = respones.credential;
var decoded = jwt_decode(token);

You should now be able to see the user's parameters.

I hope this helps, best regards.